# LiveData added as source to MediatorLiveData doesn't get into inactive state

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I might have come across a bug in MediatorLiveData source behaviour. If you add a LiveData as a source to a MediatorLiveData and then remove it again inside the observer, the source LiveData gets back into active state, even though there shouldn't be any more observers registered to it:

```
MutableLiveData<String> stringData = new MutableLiveData<String>() {
    @Override
    protected void onActive() {
        super.onActive();
        System.out.println("stringData onActive()");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInactive() {
        super.onInactive();
        System.out.println("stringData onInactive");
    }
};

MediatorLiveData<Integer> intData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
```

In your LifecycleOwner:

```
intData.addSource(stringData, s -> {
        System.out.println("stringData emitted " + s);
        intData.removeSource(stringData);
    });

// note the order here, value of the source LiveData is set before 
// observer gets registered:
stringData.setValue("blabla");
intData.observe(this, integer -> {});
```

Output:

```
System.out: stringData onActive()
System.out: stringData emitted blabla
System.out: stringData onInactive
System.out: stringData onActive()
```

What's going on here? I'd expect stringLiveData to stay inactive? Is this a bug or intended behaviour?

The interesting part is, if you call stringData.setValue() after registering the observer, the behaviour is as expected (only the first three lines of the log output).

I'm using version 1.0.0 Alpha 9-1.

Comment: I created an issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/66337741

Comment: got any result ??

Comment: Yes, the issue linked above is fixed by now.